# ORA-22813: значение операнда превышает системный лимит

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Не могу разобраться со смыслом ошибки в частном случае, дока сильно не спасла.

Выполняю запрос в SQL-окне PLSQLDeveloper'а:

```
SELECT *
  FROM TABLE(pkg_products.get_products(i_var => 'some argument'));
```

Запрос возвращает три объекта типа object. У этого object'а есть поле field1, которое тоже является типом object (который содержит поля innerField1, ..., innerFieldN). При этом, в PLSQLDeveloper'е каждое поле внутреннего объекта также выводится в одну строку. Более того, одно из внутренних полей является коллекцией типа:

```
create or replace type t_StringList as table of varchar2(32767 char)
```

То есть результат запроса будет выглядеть как:

```
|  field0  |  field1.innerField1  |  field1.innerField2 | field2  |
-------------------------------------------------------------------
|    3     |      'Hello,'        |    <Collection>     |  12312  |
|    13    |      'World'         |    <Collection>     |   3213  |
|    11    |      '!'             |    <Collection>     |   323   |
```

То есть, выводится три строки. Я хочу посмотреть на содержимое коллекции (в ячейке с коллекцией после выполнения запроса написано просто `<Collection>`). Кликаю на три точки рядом со значением ячейки:

[image: Скриншот ячейки]

После чего ожидаю увидеть в новом окне содержимое коллекции (список строк). Но вместо этого появляется указанная в заголовке ошибка:

[image: Скриншот ошибки]

При этом, в содержимом вроде как обычные короткие строки. Их видно, если выполнить PLSQL-блок:

```
declare
  c t_StringList;
begin
  c := pkg_products.get_products(i_var => 'some argument')(3).field1.innerField2;
  for i in 1..c.count loop
    dbms_output.put_line(c(i));
  end loop;
end;
```

В консоли мы увидим вполне себе ожидаемые значения:

```
Ожидаемое_значение_1
Ожидаемое_значение_2
Ожидаемое_значение_3
```

Вопрос: какова природа ошибки и можно ли её как-то решить/обойти?

Comment: [ORA-22813: Operand value exceeds system limits Tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_22813_operand_value_exceeds_system_limits.htm). Пишите в support

Comment: @avp я просмотрел статью по ссылке перед написанием вопроса. Дело в том, что в ней нет конкретики. Более того, она не учитывает специфику того, что ошибка получена не в блоке plsql-кода, а при работе со средой. Также там указывается на превышение занимаемой памяти в 30КБ, но, как я упомянул, речь о нескольких коротких строках. Я понадеялся на эмпирический опыт коллег, возможно кто-то вживую сталкивался с проблемой и нашел решение.

Comment: Поэтому я и говорю, пишите в оракловую поддержку (если она у вас оплачена, конечно)

Comment: @avp нет, к сожалению у меня нет прямого доступа к поддержке оракла. Сейчас попробовал запрос попроще - и этот не работает:
`SELECT * FROM TABLE(t_StringList('Hello','World','!'));`
Не понимаю, что происходит =\ При этом запрос: `SELECT * FROM TABLE(t_NumberList(123,321,222));` - вполне себе нормально работает (только здесь t_NumberList - это table of number, а не varchar2(32767)

Comment: @avp создал собственный тип t_ShortStringList - таблицу строк по 100 символов. Тот же код (с заменой t_StringList на t_ShortStringList) стал отрабатывать без ошибок. Плохи дела :(

Comment: Опытным путем выяснилось, что предел 2КБ - varchar2(8191) на ячейку. При 8192 уже падает ошибка

Comment: А что вы вообще делаете?  Какой лимит в БД установлен на varchar2 и какая версия БД?

Comment: @0xdb Я хочу использовать коллекцию строк внутри SELECT оператора. Видимо, когда мы кликаем на кнопку с тремя точками, то среда тоже делает подобный селект: `SELECT * FROM TABLE(t_StringList('Hello','World','!'));` БД 11gr2. Лимит БД для varchar2 - не могу знать, но в plsql блоках с переменными типа varchar2 размером до 32767 можно работать без проблем (в таблицах до 4000).

Comment: В 11 лимит 4000 байта. То  есть, вы не можете эти коллекции использовать в SQL.

Comment: @0xdb и это было бы вполне разумным ответом. Но как я писал в комментарии выше для данного запроса предельное значение  - 8191 символ. Странные дела. В итоге завел новые тип как таблицу строк по 8191 симолов, преложил в переменную с этим типом значения и уже тогда код отработал без ошибки.

Comment: _Но как я писал в комментарии выше_, комментарии не являются частью вопроса, я их обычно не читаю)) Попозже посмотрю, почему 8191.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Дело в том, что ограничение выбранo с символьной семантикой `VARCHAR2 (32767 CHAR)`, то есть макс. кол-во символов в мультибайтной кодировке может быть `FLOOR(32767/4) = 8191`.

В [PL/SQL документации](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/lnpls/plsql-data-types.html#GUID-042904FC-F495-45D1-BF3F-17378D397C00) об этом сказано следующее:

> When declaring a CHAR or VARCHAR2 variable, to ensure that it can always hold n characters in any multibyte character set, declare its length in characters—that is, CHAR(n CHAR) or VARCHAR2(n CHAR), where n does not exceed FLOOR(32767/4) = 8191.

Этот лимит проверяется при конвертировании PL/SQL символьного типа в соответствующий ему SQL тип, при этом компилятор не учитавает, сколько символов действительно содержится в сущности этого типа.

Можно указать макс. длину в байтах, тогда будет работать ([на db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=7b5b797fb6aa1b525f9f8efd539c6ad0)):

```
create or replace type StringList as table of varchar2 (32767 byte);
/
select column_value res from table (StringList ('abc','def')) 
/

RES
--------
abc
def
```